# 'Procedure or function insert_newemployee has too many arguments specified.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, stored-procedures

I have a new employee registration page which is used to register new employees in this I have used stored procedures to insert data into database, now I am getting this error previously it was working fine

This is where I pass values to stored procedures

```
protected void btnbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            upload_photo();
            uploadfile();





                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("insert_newemployee", con);
                com.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", txtfname.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lastname", txtlaname.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", ddlselect.SelectedValue.ToString());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateofBirthday", txtdob.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobilenumber", txtmnumber.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Alternatenumber", txtanumber.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emailid", txtemail.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AlternateEmail", txtaemail.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fathername", txtfaname.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mothername", txtmoname.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AadhaarCardNo", txtacno.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PanCardNo", txtpcno.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PassportNo", txtpassno.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txtuname.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtpwd.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@photo", ((ViewState["photoupload"].ToString() == null || ViewState["photoupload"].ToString() == "") ? "-" : ViewState["photoupload"].ToString()));
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Otherfiles", ((ViewState["fileupload"].ToString() == null || ViewState["fileupload"].ToString() == "" ) ? "-" : ViewState["fileupload"].ToString()));
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RAddressLine1", txtraline1.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RAddressLine2", txtraline2.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RCity", txtrcity.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RState", txtrstate.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RZipCode", txtrzcode.Text);
               com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RCountry", txtrcountry.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PAddressLine1", txtpaline1.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PAddressLine2", txtpaline2.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PCity", txtpcity.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PState", txtpstate.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PZipCode", txtpzcode.Text);
               com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PCountry", txtpcountry.Text);
               com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OAddressLine1", txtoaline1.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OAddressLine2", txtoaline2.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OCity", txtocity.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OState", txtostate.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OZipCode", txtozcode.Text);
                 com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OCountry", txtocountry.Text);
                 com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Createdby", Session["User_id"].ToString());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeId",Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["empseque"]));
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@result", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                // com.Parameters.Add(sp4);
                con.Open();
                int output = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                int result = Convert.ToInt32(com.Parameters["@result"].Value);
                con.Close();

                if (result == 1)
                {

                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "popup", "alert(' Successfully Registered!');window.location.href = 'Newemployee.aspx'", true);
                }

                else if (result == 0)
                {

                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "popup", "alert('Email Already Exist');", true);
                }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }

    private void upload_photo()
    {
        if (uploadphoto.HasFile)
        {
            try
            {
                string photoupload = Path.GetFileName(uploadphoto.FileName);

                string photo_upload = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + photoupload ;
                ViewState["photoupload"] = photo_upload;


                uploadphoto.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/photoupload/") + photo_upload);


                string s = "1";
                //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "popup", "alert(' Only doc files are accepted!');", true);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "popup", "alert(' Exception : " + ex + "');", true);
            }
        }

    }

    private void uploadfile()
    {
        if (Uploadofiles.HasFile)
        {
            try
            {
                string file_upload = Path.GetFileName(Uploadofiles.FileName);

                string upload_file = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + file_upload ;
                ViewState["fileupload"] = upload_file;
                Uploadofiles.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/otherfileupload/") + upload_file);

                string s = "2";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "popup", "alert(' Exception : " + ex + "');", true);
            }
        }

    }
```

This is my stored procedure

```
USE [PMS v1.0]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[insert_newemployee]    Script Date: 20-02-2019 09:57:56 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[insert_newemployee]
(

@firstname nvarchar(30),
@lastname nvarchar(20),
@Gender nvarchar(20),
@DateofBirthday date,
@password nvarchar(30),
@Fathername nvarchar(20),
@Mothername nvarchar(20),
@Mobilenumber nvarchar(20),
@Alternatenumber nvarchar(20),
@Emailid nvarchar(30),
@AlternateEmail nvarchar(30),
@AadhaarCardNo nvarchar(15),
@PanCardNo nvarchar(15),
@PassportNo nvarchar(15),
@UserName nvarchar(20),
@photo varchar(250),
@Otherfiles varchar(250),
@RAddressLine1 nvarchar(30),
@RAddressLine2 nvarchar(30),
@RCity nvarchar(30),
@RState nvarchar(15),
@RZipCode nvarchar(10),
@RCountry nvarchar(50),
@PAddressLine1 nvarchar(20),
@PAddressLine2 nvarchar(10),
@PCity nvarchar(10),
@PState nvarchar(10),
@PZipCode nvarchar(20),
@PCountry nvarchar(50),
@OAddressLine1 nvarchar(20),
@OAddressLine2 nvarchar(20),
@OCity nvarchar(30),
@OState nvarchar(30),
@OZipCode nvarchar(30),
@OCountry nvarchar(50),
@Createdby int,

@result int out
)

as
begin
if not exists(select Employeeid from newemployee where Emailid=@Emailid)
begin

insert into newemployee(
firstname,
lastname,
Gender,
DateofBirthday,
password,
Fathername,
Mothername,
Mobilenumber,
Alternatenumber,
Emailid,
AlternateEmail,
AadhaarCardNo,
PanCardNo,
PassportNo,
UserName,
photo,
Otherfiles,
RAddressLine1,
RAddressLine2,
RCity,
RState,
RZipCode,
RCountry,
PAddressLine1,
PAddressLine2,
PCity,
PState,
PZipCode,
PCountry,
OAddressLine1,
OAddressLine2,
OCity,
OState,
OZipCode,
OCountry,
Createdby)
values(
@firstname,
@lastname,
@Gender,
@DateofBirthday,
@password,
@Fathername,
@Mothername,
@Mobilenumber,
@Alternatenumber,
@Emailid,
@AlternateEmail,
@AadhaarCardNo,
@PanCardNo,
@PassportNo,
@UserName,
@photo,
@Otherfiles,
@RAddressLine1,
@RAddressLine2,
@RCity,
@RState,
@RZipCode,
@RCountry,
@PAddressLine1,
@PAddressLine2,
@PCity,
@PState,
@PZipCode,
@PCountry,
@OAddressLine1,
@OAddressLine2,
@OCity,
@OState,
@OZipCode,
@OCountry,
@Createdby)

set @result=1

end
else
begin

set @result=0

end

end
```

I have checked it hell lot of times both values are same.

Comment: As per what the error **Procedure or function insert_newemployee has too many arguments specified.** says is that the number of parameters passed to SQL server procedure named `insert_newemployee` from your application(*i.e. 39*) are more than the number of parameters that are supported by the Procedure (*i.e. 38  as per your code*). So, I think you might have an extra parameter defined in your app code or a parameter not defined in your procedure.

Comment: and F.Y.I the parameter named `@EmployeeId` passed from your app code is not available in the procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 37 parameters to the query and 38 supplied. My guess is that if it was working originally then someone has changed the procedure.
Whenever I get this error (and it happens a lot due to the use of SPs in many different apps with many different people changing them) I copy the parameters into notepad++ from code and sql and compare.